Concatenate multiple .ts files into single mp4 without ffmpeg usage
How to concatenate multiple .ts files into single mp4 without ffmpeg usage on Java (Android/Kotlin)?
FFMpeg it's huge library in terms of size for android applications itself and I'm sure there is a way to concatenate ts's without that library.
How to solve this on Java?
If simply concatenate files via byte-to-byte way in result we will get playable, but not seekable .mp4 file.

It doesn't look like a good idea. Media containers usually do not support the physical concatenation of files. So, inevitably, it means getting inside each container, extracting the pieces of the streams, concatenating them, taking into account their synchronization, and so on. And you have to create a new container instance out of them. Doing all that looks like implementing a good piece of code similar to much of FFMpeg code. But FFMpeg already does it perfectly...
